# How to hide rectangle annotation while scrolling

Tags: c#, charts

1 - I have vertical line annotation to show todays date and rectangle annotation, while scrolling the line be he hide it but the rectangle don't!

(I know that I must use `RA.visible=false` but I need an event and a condition)

2 - I want to fix the view of the chart when it is displayed at the beginning to show line of today because I must move the scroll bar to get it.

this is the code of annotations:

```
  VerticalLineAnnotation LA = new VerticalLineAnnotation();
  DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
  ChartArea ca= GanttChart.ChartAreas[0];
  LA.AxisX = ca.AxisX;
  LA.AxisY = ca.AxisY;
  LA.Y = DateTime.ParseExact(today.ToShortDateString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null).ToOADate();

  LA.X = LA.Y;
  LA.LineWidth = 1;
  LA.IsInfinitive = true;
  LA.LineColor = Color.Red;
  LA.ClipToChartArea = ca.Name;
  RectangleAnnotation RA = new RectangleAnnotation();
  RA.AxisX = ca.AxisX;
  RA.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
  RA.ToolTip = "Aujourd'hui \nLe "+today.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
  RA.Width = 20 * 0.07;         
  RA.Height = 8 * 0.01;        
  RA.LineColor = Color.Red;
  RA.BackColor = Color.Red;
  RA.AxisY = ca.AxisY;
  RA.Y = -RA.Height;
  RA.X = LA.X - RA.Width / 2;
  GanttChart.Annotations.Add(LA);

  GanttChart.Annotations.Add(RA);
```

[image]

**EDIT** my problem while scrolling, the rectangle still moving and didn't dispear may be I nead to know the width of chart area?

[image]

**update** 
I tried this code but rectangle is no more visible!

```
private void GanttChart_AxisViewChanged(object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
    {


        Axis ay = GanttChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
        if (ay.Minimum == ay.ScaleView.Position)
        { RA.Visible = e.NewPosition == e.Axis.Minimum; }
        else
        { RA.Visible = e.NewPosition == e.Axis.Minimum; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution which worked for me if anyone need it

```
  private void GanttChart_AxisViewChanged(object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
    {
        // LA VerticalLineAnnotation
        if (LA.Y > e.Axis.ScaleView.ViewMaximum || LA.Y < e.Axis.ScaleView.ViewMinimum)
        { RA.Visible = false; } 

        else
        {
            RA.Visible = true;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All aspects of **scrolling** and **zooming** are handled by the axes' `ScaleView` elements.

To adapt the chart during or after scrolling you can use the `AxisViewChanging` and `AxisViewChanged` events.

To compare the scrolled and unscrolled state you can test for example `ScaleView.Position` or `e.NewPosition` against `axis.Minimum` or `e.Axis.Minimum`.

Example:

```
private void chart1_AxisViewChanged(object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewPosition == e.Axis.Minimum)
    { action1 }  // unscrolled
    else
    { action2 }  // scrolled
}
```

In your case the body can be simplified to: `RA.Visible = e.NewPosition == e.Axis.Minimum;`

**Note:** The above example doesn't specify which axis to watch, i.e. **both** axes are being observed. If for example you only want to watch the **y-axis** you should change it to:

```
private void chart1_AxisViewChanged(object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
{
    Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    if (ay.Minimum == ay.ScaleView.Position) 
    { action1 }
    else
    { action2 }
}
```

In your case (a bar charttype getting scrolled horizontally) you most likely you want to watch **only the y-axis**.

Comment: see **EDIT** please, I tried your answer but the rectangle is not visible at all

Comment: Which axis did you test? You are scrolling horizontally, right? For all types of bar charts this means you need to test the y-axis. (I made a mistake there!)

Comment: So, did you use the last code example? does the event fire? Here the rectangle disappears (and re-appears) fine.. But your question was maybe not clear enough for me to understand what you have and what you want..

Comment: what action did  you put?

Comment: Just what I wrote: `RA.Visible = e.NewPosition == e.Axis.Minimum;` Note: for this you need to move the declaration of the RA to class level. Or access it from the chart.Annotations collection: `chart1.Annotations["Annotation2"].Visible = ay.Minimum == ca.AxisY.ScaleView.Position;` . Note that you better set a clear Name when creating the Annotations instead of the confusing default Name..

Comment: RA is already declared in the class level (I put it in the code just for you to understand what is RA). maybe I must test on the position of RA not axis y

Comment: No, I don't think so. I used your code directly and it works. Do update the question with you current chart_AxisViewChanged event!

Comment: a) do use the correct code: Yours is a mixture of both examples! use only the last one, i.e. `ay` always. b) both branches do the same, which makes no sense. Insert maybe a `!` in one branch!

Comment: I tried your code many times and changed but it didn't solve my problem then I tried to test on the Line annotation then it works, thank you for all your efforts which guided me to the solution